# Exclude images for printing pdf

Tags: graphics, pdf, printing

I have a document that has images that are very, very dark.  As such, they *should not be printed* when the user goes to print.  Somebody I'm working with loves to print, and they use a lot of toner this way.

Is there a way to make an image *not print* in the hard copy paper view, but show up in the electronic view?

Comment: I think this is a little off-topic since it's a PDF specification related issue but I've learned quite a while ago that anything is possible in here.

Comment: @percusse I believe it's on-topic because I'm pretty sure it _is_ possible with PDF and the true problem is: How to do it in LaTeX.

Comment: You should search for Optional Content Groups (OCG) and setting the PrintState and ViewState. The hyperref package can do this for link colors, maybe have a look there.

Comment: Well, you can build two pdfs, one with the option `draft`, one without. Option `draft` forces to hold only the place of the image.

Comment: Another solution would be to increase the gamma by a factor of 20 or 100 (so that the images are significantly washed out) in print. I wonder if this is also possible.

Comment: @JuriRobl I believe that this is the correct way of thinking! I completely forgot that `hyperlink` already uses this feature.

Comment: @bobobobo: With pngs it may be possible with pdftex.

Comment: Have you considered that your print loving co-worker may end up firing of a gazillion copies of the document while trying to figure out why his images won't print?  Whatever the answer to your question ends up being, I'm going to use it for entertainment purposes ;)

Comment: see also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122793/create-element-in-pdf-that-doesnt-print-to-paper

Answer (score 6):

If you are using `pdflatex` or `lualatex`, `pdftex.def` allows you to specify an alternate image to be used for printing:

```
\includegraphics[print=print.png]{screen.pdf}
```

This will probably only work with Adobe Reader.

Comment: While this sounds like a really great idea, I tried it pdflatex=>pdf file=>Adobe Reader=>Print XPS file, but the xps file still had the {screen.pdf} image