# Create element in pdf that doesn't print to paper

Tags: pdf, printing

I'm creating a fancy header with hyperlinks ([see here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122792/breadcrumb-hyperlink-header)) for a large document. However, if/when this document is printed, this header is not useful and uses up ink and space. Is it possible to include an element in a pdf file such that it is not actually printed to paper but does display on screen?

Comment: Most likely PDF annotations would be the way to go. However, this may be viewer-dependent.

Comment: By default, hyperref creates boxes around links tht are not printed. So at least conditional printing is possible for rules/lines.

Comment: Can we achieve this using `PDF` layers? A combination of non-printable and printable layer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Jagath already mention a solution in his comment:

> Can we achieve this using PDF layers? A combination of non-printable and printable layer?

Heres the corresponding MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{ocg-p} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
text

\begin{ocg}[printocg=never]{Notprinted}{noprint}{1}
This paragraph is never printed
\end{ocg}

Text after non print 
\end{document}
```

I tested it with Sumatra and Acrobat XI.

With the same technique you may also put things on a print, but not on a screen:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{ocg-p} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
test

\begin{ocg}[printocg=always]{Onlyprint}{onlyprint}{0}
This paragraph is printed, but not shown by default
\end{ocg}

test after
\end{document}
```

Lets combine it with a [coffee stain](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67656/are-there-other-fun-packages-like-the-coffee-stains-package), an image of a fly ;)