# Can LaTeX do non-printable graphical elements?

Tags: graphics, margins, book-design, printing, text-decorations

Is there a way to make some graphical elements to be non-printable, i.e. prints as white, while staying fully visible on screen?

Here's a MWE to play and have fun with:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newlength{\distance}
\setlength{\distance}{0.0in}
\newlength{\rulethickness}
\setlength{\rulethickness}{0.5in}
\newlength{\ruleheight}
\setlength{\ruleheight}{\paperheight}
\newlength{\xoffset}
\newlength{\yoffset}
\setlength{\yoffset}{0pt}

\AddToShipoutPicture{%
    \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
    \ifodd\value{page}%
        \setlength{\xoffset}{\distance}%
    \else
        \setlength{\xoffset}{\dimexpr\paperwidth-\rulethickness-\distance}%
    \fi
    \AtPageLowerLeft{%
        \put(\LenToUnit{\xoffset},\LenToUnit{\yoffset}){%
        \colorbox{lightgray}{\parbox[b][\ruleheight][c]{\rulethickness}{%
        \centering
        \ifodd\value{page}%
            \rotatebox[origin=cB]{90}{\color{red}{\large{\normalfont\textsc{Copyright notice}}}}%
        \else
            \rotatebox[origin=cB]{90}{\color{blue}{\huge{\normalfont\textsc{Some Title}}}}%
        \fi
    }}}}%
}

\begin{document}

Test
\newpage
Another page

\end{document}
```

This code draws a gray vertical bar in the inner margins, with some copyright notice.  I need it to stay visible while reading the PDF document on screen.  But I would also like it to turn completely invisible when printed on paper.  Is that possible with some LaTeX commands?

---

**EDIT:** Oups !  This question appears to be a duplicate of this one : [Create element in pdf that doesn't print to paper](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122793/create-element-in-pdf-that-doesnt-print-to-paper)

Comment: Also, the `accsupp` package allows one thing to go to the visible layer and something else to go to the PDF data layer.  For example, like this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241968/how-to-protect-a-word-from-finding-by-google-search-machines/388006#388006.  However, this may not be exactly what you are looking for, as this is more for copy/paste protection.

Comment: The OCG method presented in the linked answer works only with a small set of PDF viewers: Acrobat Reader and Chrome PDF plugin. Another solution could be based on a non-printable PDF annotation which works with most other (or all?) PDF viewers too, such as Evince and Okular.

Answer (score 3):

PDF Layers can be configured to not be printed on paper. This solution is used in the answer that was linked in the question. While this OCG-based method can be used with any typeset content, it is supported by only a small set of PDF viewers, namely Acrobat Reader and the Chromium PDF plugin.

For page elements that can be put in a box, as in the present question, another approach based on non-printable PDF annotations is possible. This method works with all known PDF viewers. With this approach, the optional page elements are shown as appearances of non-printable, non-interactive PDF annotations:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{pdfbase}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\let\tpPdfAnnot\pbs_pdfannot:nnnn\let\tpPdfLastAnn\pbs_pdflastann:
\let\tpAppendToFields\pbs_appendtofields:n
\def\tpPdfXform{\pbs_pdfxform:nnnnn{1}{1}{}{}}
\let\tpPdfLastXform\pbs_pdflastxform:
\ExplSyntaxOff

% odd
\begin{lrbox}{0}
  \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
  \rotatebox{90}{%
    \colorbox{lightgray}{%
      \makebox[\paperheight][c]{%
        \raisebox{-0.5\totalheight+\depth}[0.25in][0.25in]{\large\scshape\color{red}Copyright notice}%
      }%
    }%
  }
\end{lrbox}
\tpPdfXform{0}\edef\oddElem{\tpPdfLastXform}

%even
\begin{lrbox}{0}
  \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
  \rotatebox{90}{%
    \colorbox{lightgray}{%
      \makebox[\paperheight][c]{%
        \raisebox{-0.5\totalheight+\depth}[0.25in][0.25in]{\huge\scshape\color{blue}Some Title}%
      }%
    }%
  }
\end{lrbox}
\tpPdfXform{0}\edef\evenElem{\tpPdfLastXform}

\newlength\xoffset
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
  \ifodd\value{page}%
      \setlength{\xoffset}{0pt}%
  \else
      \setlength{\xoffset}{\paperwidth-0.5in}%
  \fi
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \put(\LenToUnit{\xoffset},0){%
      \tpPdfAnnot{0.5in}{\paperheight}{0pt}{%
        /Subtype/Widget/FT/Btn/T (elem.\value{page})%
        /AP<<
          \ifodd\value{page}%
            /N \oddElem        % normal appearance
          \else
            /N \evenElem
          \fi
        >>%
        /Ff 65537 % non-interactive  push button
        /F 0 % visible, but no-print
      }%
      \tpAppendToFields{\tpPdfLastAnn}
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

Test
\newpage
Another page

\end{document}
```